# How to debug the grails-gorm files in intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, grails, grails-orm, remote-debugging

I am able to debug my application by remote debug in intellij. But how to debug the method like 
list in below example.

```
Student.createCriteria().list {
                    'in'('Id', params.id)
}
```

I want to debug the list method to get the query which is getting fired but debug point don't go there.

Comment: Debug will certainly help you for complex cases. For a simple case, you may also find it easier to just turn up logging to print the queries generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug GORM code pretty much like you debug all JVM classes.  You can `step-into` the GORM code.  If you don't want to step into the GORM code but instead want to put the breakpoint in the GORM code directly, it is impossible to say for sure where you should put a breakpoint because I don't know which GORM implementation you are using and which version of that implementation.  If you are using GORM for Hibernate version `7.0.3.RELEASE`, then you may want to put a breakpoint at https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/df05ec7e99a6b12718dfc814a7cbe4073b09a881/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/query/AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.java#L1570.

I hope that helps.